# Xceed wpf wizard - how do I set an application image?

Tags: c#, xceed

I am using the Xceed wpf Wizard, which is really useful, but I have a problem with it. On the left side, where there would usually be an image for the application, there is just a gray area. I have an image I want to add, but cannot find a way of doing it.

Is there a method of setting this image?

Comment: It is not necessarily only an image, [it could be anything](https://imgur.com/P0HZOp0), including an image... you need to set the `ExteriorPanelContent`.

Comment: Thank you! It is obvious when you see it, but not documented clearly anywhere that I can find.

Comment: It's your job to crack it opened and find out...:O) Please post your solution and mark your question as answered.

Comment: Where's the code in your solution... ? :O)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As per @jsanalytics comment, the solution is to set the ExteriorPanelContent on the Wizard page to the relevant object (an image in this case).

This does also mean that the image (or whatever) can change per page displayed.